# Doctrine: I cannot find a reason for "A New entity was found through the relationship that was not configured to cascade persist..."

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

**UPDATE:** I've found the problem, [but I don't understand why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42233245/it-seems-i-have-two-doctrine-entity-managers-but-i-want-only-one-o-o) it exists and I don't know how to fix it.

Practically, I do a check to see if the current processing `Job` is a retried one:

```
        if ($job->isRetry()) {
            $this->entityManager->persist($job->getRetryOf());
            $this->ioWriter->noteLineNoBg(sprintf(
                '[%s] Job "%s" on Queue "%s": this is a retry of original process #%s.',
                $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), $job->getId(), $job->getQueue(), $job->getRetryOf()->getId()
            ));
        }
```

So, at this time, the retried `Job` is loaded and when I go to update the current `Job` the retried one is already hydrated BUT NOT MANAGED BY THE ENTITY MANAGER! Why isn't it? Does this mean that each time I call `Job#isRetry()` I have then to persist again the retried `Job`?

**MORE: If I persist again, I have duplicated entries in the database!**

Reading around here on StackOverflow in those days, I've read another question of a dev with a similar problem to mine: he told about the use of two distinct entity managers: how can I verify if the Entity manager used by my entities is the same used by my services?

**THIS IS MY ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I have a `Job` entity that represents a command to be executed.

Now, if the command fails, I create a new `Job` entity that retries the previously failed `Job`.

The problem is that I ever receive an error:

> A new entity was found through the relationship
>   'SerendipityHQ\Bundle\CommandsQueuesBundle\Entity\Job#retriedBy' that
>   was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: 3. To
>   solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on
>   this unknown entity or configure cascade persist  this association in
>   the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}).

I know, is a very common problem here on StackOverflow: I've searched for a solution for days but no one has this error with a `one-to-one` self-referencing entity. So their solution are not suitable for me.

```
/**
 * Basic properties and methods o a Job.
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="SerendipityHQ\Bundle\CommandsQueuesBundle\Repository\JobRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="queues_scheduled_jobs")
 */
class Job
{
    ...

    /**
     * @var  Job $retryOf If this Job is a retry of another job, here there is the Job of which this is the retry
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="SerendipityHQ\Bundle\CommandsQueuesBundle\Entity\Job", inversedBy="retriedBy")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="retry_of", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $retryOf;

    /**
     * @var  Job $retriedBy
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="SerendipityHQ\Bundle\CommandsQueuesBundle\Entity\Job", mappedBy="retryOf")ì
     */
    private $retriedBy;

    ...
}
```

**FIRST QUESTION: Is this maping correct? Does it have any error?**

I've tried all possible things: trying to persist both entities, detaching and then re-persisting, refreshing, fetching `EAGER`, setting both `retryOf` and `retriedBy` when using `setRetryOf()` (this shuld be the owning side, right?)... Also using cascade options (but this duplicates the entities in the databse instead of updating the already present ones) Anything! The problem persists.

It seems it arises when I load from the database the entity.

Lets see this log:

```
[INFO] [2017-02-14 15:30:42] Job "1" on Queue "default": Initializing the process.                                      
"Marking job 1 with status pending"
[INFO] Checking 1 running jobs...                                                                                       
"Start marking 1 as retried"
"Marking job 1 with status retried"
[✖] [2017-02-14 15:30:57] Job "1" on Queue "default": Process failed.                                                   
 ! [NOTE] [2017-02-14 15:30:57] Job "1" on Queue "default": Retry with Job "3" (Attempt #1/3).                          
[INFO] [2017-02-14 15:31:00] Job "3" on Queue "default": Initializing the process.                                      
 ! [NOTE] [2017-02-14 15:31:00] Job "3" on Queue "default": this is a retry of original process #1.                     
"Marking job 3 with status pending"
[INFO] Checking 1 running jobs...                                                                                       
"Start marking 3 as retried"
"Marking job 3 with status retried"
[✖] [2017-02-14 15:31:17] Job "3" on Queue "default": Process failed.                                                   
 ! [NOTE] [2017-02-14 15:31:17] Job "3" on Queue "default": Retry with Job "4" (Attempt #2/3).                          
[INFO] [2017-02-14 15:31:19] Job "4" on Queue "default": Initializing the process.                                      
 ! [NOTE] [2017-02-14 15:31:19] Job "4" on Queue "default": this is a retry of original process #3.                     
"Marking job 4 with status pending"

Exception: A new entity was found through the relationship 'SerendipityHQ\Bundle\CommandsQueuesBundle\Entity\Job#retriedBy' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: 3. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist  this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}).
```

See the last lines:

```
[INFO] [2017-02-14 15:31:19] Job "4" on Queue "default": Initializing the process.                                      
 ! [NOTE] [2017-02-14 15:31:19] Job "4" on Queue "default": this is a retry of original process #3.                     
"Marking job 4 with status pending"
```

At this stage I have just retrieved the `Job` #4 from the database and trying to update its status from `new` to `pending`.

At this point, I get the error for the Entity #3 that has a not managed entity at property `retriedBy`. But this entity is the currently updating `Job` #4! How is it possible it cannot find it? And also if I persist it again the error still persist.

I really don't know where to look for the bug. Is anyone able to help me, please?

**SOME MORE CODE**

The problem arises when I try to update the status of a `new` Job to `pending` and this changing `Job` has both `retryOf` and a `retriedBy` properties set.

To change the status of a `Job` I use a class [`JobsMarker`](https://github.com/Aerendir/bundle-commands-queues/blob/%232-Retry-logic/Util/JobsMarker.php).

The error triggers at method [`markJobAsPending()`](https://github.com/Aerendir/bundle-commands-queues/blob/%232-Retry-logic/Util/JobsMarker.php#L103-L111):

```
// Utils\JobsMarker.php
public function markJobAsPending(Job $job, array $info, Daemon $daemon)
{
    $this->markJob($job, Job::STATUS_PENDING, $info, $daemon);
}
```

The entity manager is ever the same and I call `$em->flush()` a lot of times during the `Job`s processing to update the status of the `Job`s (maybe the cause is this? It seems strange, really!).

The flow is this:

1. [I get the `Job` to process from the database](https://github.com/Aerendir/bundle-commands-queues/blob/%232-Retry-logic/Service/QueuesDaemon.php#L159);
2. Mark it [as `aborted`](https://github.com/Aerendir/bundle-commands-queues/blob/%232-Retry-logic/Service/QueuesDaemon.php#L201) or [as `pending`](https://github.com/Aerendir/bundle-commands-queues/blob/%232-Retry-logic/Service/QueuesDaemon.php#L224);
3. When the `Job` exits, I mark it with the appropriate status: if it fails [and can be retried](https://github.com/Aerendir/bundle-commands-queues/blob/%232-Retry-logic/Service/QueuesDaemon.php#L410-L424), [I create a new `Job`](http://$retryJob%20=%20$this-%3EjobsMarker-%3EmarkJobAsRetried($job,%20$info);):

   // Util\JobsMarker.php
   public function markJobAsRetried(Job $job, array $info)
   {
       // Create a new retry Job
       $retryJob = $job->createRetryJob();

   ```
   // Set this retry Job as a retry of the original one
   $retryJob->setRetryOf($job);

   $this->entityManager->persist($retryJob);

   $this->markJobAsClosed($job, Job::STATUS_RETRIED, $info);

   return $retryJob;
   ```

   }

So, what happens?

1. I create Job #1 and this fails;
2. I create a new Job #3 ([because I already have for other reasons a Job #2](https://github.com/Aerendir/bundle-commands-queues/blob/%232-Retry-logic/Controller/QueuesController.php#L111-L125));
3. I get Job #3 and mark is status as `pending` (`Utils\JobsMarker);
4. Job #3 fails and I create Job #4.
5. I get Job #4 and marking it as `pending` I receive the exeception about the not managed entity. And I don't really understand why!

Hope this will help you to help me!

Comment: Can you provide the code where the new job is created after previous job failure ?

Comment: Yes, for sure! I'm goingi to update the question!

Comment: @OlivierC I've found the cause of the bug, but don't know why it is happening! Can you find the reason?

Comment: I was about to start working on it. But the first things I would have try was to add nullable true for both relations, add cascade persist in the annotation and explicitly set the retriedBy property

Comment: @OlivierC, done: adding the cascade persisting cause a duplication of rows in the database. The cause is due to the fact that the repositories are using a different entity manager than the one used by my services. So, using cascade persist, forces Doctrine to re-enter the rows. See my current discussion about the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42233245/1399706