# It seems I have two Doctrine Entity Managers but I want only one! o.O

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I've spent last days solving [a very subtle bug in my bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42228866/doctrine-i-cannot-find-a-reason-for-a-new-entity-was-found-through-the-relatio).

Practically I get a `Job` entity from the database. This entity has a `one-to-one`, self-referencing relation to another `Job` entity on the property `retryOf`.

When I try to update the retrieved `Job#status` property, I get the following exception thrown:

> [Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException]
>   A new entity was found through the relationship
>   'SerendipityHQ\Bundle\CommandsQueuesBundle\Entity\Job#retryOf' that
>   was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity:
>   SerendipityHQ\Bundle\CommandsQueuesBundle\Entity\Job@000000004ab2727c0000000065
>   d15d74. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call
>   EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade
>   persist  this association in the mapping for example
>   @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot find out which
>   entity causes the      problem implement
>   'SerendipityHQ\Bundle\CommandsQueuesBundle\Entity\Job#__toString()' to
>   get a clue.

In the end I discovered that the `EntityManager` I use to retrieve and persist/flush entities is different from the one used by my entities to manage themselves and retrieve related entities.

So, my question is: assuming I'm injecting the right `EntityManager` in my services (`@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager`):

1. Why my services use one and the repositories use another?
2. How can I make my entities use the same I inject in services? (or how can I inject the same used by my entities - is the same)?

### HOW I INJECT THE `EntityManager`

```
services:
    queues:
        class: SerendipityHQ\Bundle\CommandsQueuesBundle\Service\QueuesManager
        arguments: ["@commands_queues.do_not_use.entity_manager"]
    #This service is meant to be privately used by QueuesRunCommand
    commands_queues.do_not_use.daemon:
        class: SerendipityHQ\Bundle\CommandsQueuesBundle\Service\QueuesDaemon
        arguments: ["@commands_queues.do_not_use.entity_manager"]
```

The `EntityManager` is created in the `SHQCommandsQueuesExtension` ([see its code on GitHub](https://github.com/Aerendir/bundle-commands-queues/blob/master/DependencyInjection/SHQCommandsQueuesExtension.php)).

**The problem is really hard, as I receive the error but I cannot persist again in the entity manager used by services: this cause a duplication of rows in the database!**

### HOW I SPECIFY THE `JobRepository` CLASS

```
/**
 * Basic properties and methods o a Job.
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="SerendipityHQ\Bundle\CommandsQueuesBundle\Repository\JobRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="queues_scheduled_jobs")
 */
class Job
{
...
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
class JobRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    /**
     * @param int $id
     *
     * @return null|object|Job
     */
    public function findOneById(int $id)
    {
        return parent::findOneBy(['id' => $id]);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a Job that can be run.
     *
     * A Job can be run if it hasn't a startDate in the future and if its parent Jobs are already terminated with
     * success.
     *
     * @return null|Job
     */
    public function findNextRunnableJob()
    {
        // Collects the Jobs that have to be excluded from the next findNextJob() call
        $excludedJobs = [];

        while (null !== $job = $this->findNextJob($excludedJobs)) {
            // If it can be run...
            if (false === $job->hasNotFinishedParentJobs()) {
                // ... Return it
                return $job;
            }

            // The Job cannot be run or its lock cannot be acquired
            $excludedJobs[] = $job->getId();

            // Remove it from the Entity Manager to free some memory
            $this->_em->detach($job);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Finds the next Job to process.
     *
     * @param array $excludedJobs The Jobs that have to be excluded from the SELECT
     *
     * @return Job|null
     */
    private function findNextJob(array $excludedJobs = [])
    {
        $queryBuilder = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
        $queryBuilder->select('j')->from('SHQCommandsQueuesBundle:Job', 'j')
            ->orderBy('j.priority', 'ASC')
            ->addOrderBy('j.createdAt', 'ASC')
            // The status MUST be NEW
            ->where($queryBuilder->expr()->eq('j.status', ':status'))->setParameter('status', Job::STATUS_NEW)
            // It hasn't an executeAfterTime set or the set time is in the past
            ->andWhere(
                $queryBuilder->expr()->orX(
                    $queryBuilder->expr()->isNull('j.executeAfterTime'),
                    $queryBuilder->expr()->lt('j.executeAfterTime', ':now')
                )
            )->setParameter('now', new \DateTime(), 'datetime');

        // If there are excluded Jobs...
        if (false === empty($excludedJobs)) {
            // The ID hasn't to be one of them
            $queryBuilder->andWhere(
                $queryBuilder->expr()->notIn('j.id', ':excludedJobs')
            )->setParameter('excludedJobs', $excludedJobs, Connection::PARAM_INT_ARRAY);
        }

        return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->setMaxResults(1)->getOneOrNullResult();
    }
}
```

The repository is simply specified in the `@Entity` annotation in the `Job` entity class.

## TESTS

### Proving the two `EntityManager`s are different

#### TEST 1. Persist again in the `EntityManager` I'm using in services: works, the exception is not thrown anymore

This forces me to do something like this:

```
        ...

        // SerendipityHQ\Bundle\CommandsQueuesBundle\Service\QueuesDaemon
        if ($job->isRetry()) {
            // Here I have to persist AGAIN in my injected entity manager the Entity referenced by Job#retryOf
            $this->entityManager->persist($job->getRetryOf());
            ...
        }

        ...
```

If I don't do this, the exception is again thrown.

**So it seems that the `annotations` loads entities using an `EntityManager` and my service, instead, use the entity manager I've specified...** This is very strange and never happened to me! O.O

#### TEST 2. `VarDump`: Shows two different unique identifiers

With a simple `VarDumper::dump($passedEntityManager)` and `VarDumper::dump($entity)` I've discovered that they use two different entity managers:

```
        ...

        // SerendipityHQ\Bundle\CommandsQueuesBundle\Service\QueuesDaemon
        if ($job->isRetry()) {
            //$job->setRetryOf($this->entityManager->getRepository('SHQCommandsQueuesBundle:Job')->findOneById($job->getRetryOf()->getId()));
            VarDumper::dump($this->entityManager);
            VarDumper::dump($job);
            die;
            ...
        }

        ...
```

The result is:

```
EntityManager58a434fb99fbf_546a8d27f194334ee012bfe64f629947b07e4919\__CG__\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager {#768
  -delegate: DoctrineORMEntityManager_000000007aac762a000000007cf8d85284b5df468960200ce73b9230d68d81c1 {#773 …2}
  -container: appDevDebugProjectContainer {#495 …12}
  -config: null
  -conn: null
  -metadataFactory: null
  -unitOfWork: null
  -eventManager: null
  -proxyFactory: null
  -repositoryFactory: null
  -expressionBuilder: null
  -closed: false
  -filterCollection: null
  -cache: null
}
SerendipityHQ\Bundle\CommandsQueuesBundle\Entity\Job {#730
  -id: 3
  ...
  -childDependencies: Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection {#41028
    ...
    -em: Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager {#788 …11}
    ...
    #initialized: true
  }
  -parentDependencies: Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection {#41019
    ...
    -em: Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager {#788 …11}
    ...
    #initialized: true
  }
    ...
    -processedBy: SerendipityHQ\Bundle\CommandsQueuesBundle\Entity\Daemon {#806
      ...
      -processedJobs: Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection {#819
        ...
        -em: Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager {#788 …11}
        ...
        #initialized: true
      }
    }
    ...
    -childDependencies: Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection {#40899
      ...
      -em: Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager {#788 …11}
      ...
      #initialized: false
    }
    -parentDependencies: Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection {#40901
      ...
      -em: Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager {#788 …11}
      ...
      #initialized: true
    }
    ...
}
```

In entities the Entity manager is `#788`:

```
SerendipityHQ\Bundle\CommandsQueuesBundle\Entity\Job {#725
  -id: 3
  -command: "queues:test"

...

  -childDependencies: Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection {#41028
    -snapshot: []
    -owner: SerendipityHQ\Bundle\CommandsQueuesBundle\Entity\Job {#725}
    -association: array:16 [ …16]
    -em: Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager {#788 …11}
```

while my injected entity manager is `768`:

```
EntityManager58a434fb99fbf_546a8d27f194334ee012bfe64f629947b07e4919\__CG__\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager  {#768
  -delegate: DoctrineORMEntityManager_000000007aac762a000000007cf8d85284b5df468960200ce73b9230d68d81c1. {#773 …2}
```

#### TEST 3. Proving I have more than one `EntityManager`: I have

```
Aerendir$ app/console debug:container | grep EntityManager
  aws_ses_monitor.entity_manager               Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
  commands_queues.do_not_use.entity_manager    Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
  doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager          EntityManager58a434fb99fbf_546a8d27f194334ee012bfe64f629947b07e4919\__CG__\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
  stripe_bundle.entity_manager                 Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
```

This is right as I effectively have 4 entity managers and the ones reported are the ones I expect exist.

#### TEST 4. Identify which `EntityManager` is used by my services and which one is used in my repositories

```
        // SerendipityHQ\Bundle\CommandsQueuesBundle\Service\QueuesDaemon
        if ($job->isRetry()) {
            VarDumper::dump('entityManager');
            VarDumper::dump(spl_object_hash($this->entityManager));
            VarDumper::dump('aws_ses_monitor.entity_manager');
            VarDumper::dump(spl_object_hash($this->container->get('aws_ses_monitor.entity_manager')));
            VarDumper::dump('commands_queues.do_not_use.entity_manager');
            VarDumper::dump(spl_object_hash($this->container->get('commands_queues.do_not_use.entity_manager')));
            VarDumper::dump('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager');
            VarDumper::dump(spl_object_hash($this->container->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager')));
            VarDumper::dump('stripe_bundle.entity_manager');
            VarDumper::dump(spl_object_hash($this->container->get('stripe_bundle.entity_manager')));
```

die;
                ...
            }

And in the `JobRepository` class:

```
private function findNextJob(array $excludedJobs = [])
{
    VarDumper::dump('Inside repository');
    VarDumper::dump(spl_object_hash($this->getEntityManager()));
...
```

Result:

```
"Inside repository"
"00000000326f44a000000000730f8ec4"                                     
"entityManager"
"00000000326f44b400000000730f8ec4"
"aws_ses_monitor.entity_manager"
"00000000326f44b400000000730f8ec4"
"commands_queues.do_not_use.entity_manager"
"00000000326f44b400000000730f8ec4"
"doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager"
"00000000326f44b400000000730f8ec4"
"stripe_bundle.entity_manager"
"00000000326f44b400000000730f8ec4"
```

It's ever the same! This is really unexpected!!! If the `EntityManager` is ever the same:

1. Why the `Job#retryOf` object is not already persisted and I have to persist it again to not get the thrown exception?
2. Why the `VarDumper` [gives me two different internal object handles](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html#dump-examples-and-output) if the object is ever the same?

Comment: Few question to your case: Do you have entity repositories implemented? (as services? code?) How do you inject entity manager? (code?) or entity repository? (code?)

Comment: Yes, I have... Why? Not as services... I'm going to update the question... is simpler... One moment...

Comment: From the command line run: php bin/console debug:container | grep EntityManager and report the results.

Comment: I don't understand: are you saying that the existence of multiple entity managers is normal? If so, why I cannot simply flush? After all if the multiple entity manager existence is the way Doctrine works, then the retryOf Job should be already managed And I should not have to persist it again. I have to persist again in the "main" entity manager precisely because the two entity managers are different and the one that manages the Job in retryOf is the "wrong" one... did I understand what you are saying?

Comment: He is confusing entity managers with entity repositories.  Multiple entity managers is not "normal".  You need to spend some effort to configure multiple entity managers.  It is possible that you have a bundle that is doing so though very unlikely.  That is why I asked you to run the debug:container command.  It would confirm that you have multiple entity managers.  I'm actually pretty sure you only have one.  It is not clear from your posted code where $this->entityManager is coming from.  Almost seems like you injected an entity manager into your entity which would be asking for trouble.

Comment: @Cerad there are effectively multiple entity managers (3: the default one, plus other two from other two bundles - more details asap as now I'm writing with a phone). But EntityManager is passed through the services.yml, referencing doctrine.default_entity_manager. I've also tried to pass @ doctrine and then use @ doctrine->getRepositoryForClass (not sure if the method's name is this now... I'm on phone) but the result doesn't change... the problem is that JobRepo is using a different instance of EntityManager and I don't know how to identify its origin.

Comment: In my service, if I use getEntityManagersNames (again, unsure about the method's name) I have only the default entity manager... anyway asap I'll dig deeper into the problem... any suggestion about what to do to identify the entity manager used by repos and the em used in services?

Comment: @Cerad , I've updated the question to make it more clear...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TEST 5. Try to remove all the calls to `$this->entityManager->detach()`

SOLVED! The problem was a `detach()` that didn't check for the status: if a `Job` failed I simply detached it to not have it floating around in the `EntityManager` and as the bundle launches a daemon, I need to free up memory. But I need to free it up only if the `Job` is definitely failed, while if it has to be retried, I not have to detach it... Or at least I have to reload it if the processing `Job` refers to it...

Damn, building a daemon requires a lot of attention to details!